# a countable and connected metric space $X$ has only one point

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Prove that a countable and connected metric space $X$ has only one point.

Could you check my attempt? Thanks!

Suppose not. Consider two distinct point $x$ and $y$. Define $d:=d(x,y)>0$. Let $a<d$. By the connectedness of $X$, for each $\epsilon\in (0,a)$ there exists $z_{\epsilon}\in\partial B(x,\epsilon)$ where $\partial B(x,\epsilon)$ is the boundary of the open ball $B(x,\epsilon)=\{z\in X: d(z,x)<\epsilon\}$. This defines a map $\epsilon\mapsto z_{\epsilon}$ from $(0,a)$ to $X$. But this map is injective because for any distinct $\epsilon, \epsilon_1\in (0,a)$ we have $$d(z_{\epsilon},z_{\epsilon_1})\geq \big|d(z_{\epsilon},x)-d(x,z_{\epsilon_1})\big|=\big|\epsilon-\epsilon_1\big|>0$$So $z_{\epsilon}\neq z_{\epsilon_1}$.

Comment: This seems to be correct, though you could make clearer why connectedness implies the existence of this point on $\partial B(x,\epsilon)$, especially if you are submitting this as homework.

Comment: If $\partial B(x,\epsilon)=\emptyset$ for some $\epsilon\in (0,a)$, then X can be written as the disjoint union of the sets $B(x,\epsilon)$ and the interior of the complement of $B(x,\epsilon)$ which is nonempty. It means X is disconnected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is OK, but some slight simplification suggestions:

It's probably easiest to note that $B(x,\varepsilon)$ and $\{z: d(x,z) > \varepsilon\}$ are both open and non-empty, so there must be some point $z_\varepsilon$ with $d(x,z_\varepsilon) = \varepsilon$ to avoid having a disconnection for $X$. (Otherwise you need a small argument why for $z \in \partial B(x,\varepsilon)$ we have $d(x,z) = \varepsilon$).

The injectivity is then also clear: if two points have different distance to $x$, they are different points (no need for the reverse triangle inequality).